# If a value of one column appears in any of three other columns, change the value of the respective column to NA

Tags: r

I want to change the values per row in each of three columns `Q10`, `Q11`, `Q12` to `NA` conditional on the appearance of one of these values based on the column `Groups`. In my example, `Groups`in row 4 contains `Group 4` same as `Q11`. Thus, I would like to change the value for `df[4,2]` to `NA`.
I have tried to combine `rowwise()` with `mutate()` and `case_when()`, however doing so results in all three columns being populated by NAs.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Q10 = case_when(Groups %in% Q10 ~ NA, TRUE ~ Q10),
         Q11 = case_when(Groups %in% Q11 ~ NA, TRUE ~ Q11),
         Q12 = case_when(Groups %in% Q12 ~ NA, TRUE ~ Q12))
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Q10 = structure(c(8L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("Group 1", 
"Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 5", "Group 6", "Group 7", 
"Group 8", "Group 9"), class = "factor"), Q11 = structure(c(1L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", 
"Group 4", "Group 5", "Group 6", "Group 7", "Group 8", "Group 9"
), class = "factor"), Q12 = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L
), .Label = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 5", 
"Group 6", "Group 7", "Group 8", "Group 9"), class = "factor"), 
    Groups = c("Group 2", "Group 9", "Group 2", "Group 4", "Group 6", 
    "Group 7")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone should come along with a more elegant solution, but for now you can use this brute-force method that uses `which` to identify the row position of the matching values, then replace with `NA`:

```
for(xx in 1:3){
  df[which(df[xx] == df[4]), xx] <- NA
}
```

Output:

```
#   Q10     Q11     Q12     Groups 
# <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <chr>  
# 1 Group 8 Group 1 Group 3 Group 2
# 2 Group 8 Group 6 Group 5 Group 9
# 3 Group 6 Group 5 Group 4 Group 2
# 4 Group 1 NA      Group 3 Group 4
# 5 Group 7 Group 7 Group 5 Group 6
# 6 Group 6 Group 6 Group 4 Group 7
```

Comment: Thank you, @jpsmith. I do not want to change the values in the `Groups` column, but the respective value in the three other columns. So, for this example row 4 of `Q11` should be empty. :) I will try to clarify.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying! See edit and let me know if that works

Comment: My apologies, I was not clear enough again. This time, the whole row 4 is filled with NA. However, I just want df[4,2] to be NA. Where the NA should be placed can vary from row to row.

Comment: Ok - edited again, and will work to make it better, but for now should get you on your way!